# On the buyside, when people quote a 'price' for a plain vanilla interest rate swap, does it include accrued interest?

Tags: interest-rates, swaps, accrued-interest

The valuation date falls in between coupon payment days on the swap, does the 'price' of a swap understood to include the accrued interest (interest from the previous payment date to the valuation date, as a fraction of the number of days in between) on both legs? Or is it only PV (only counting cashflows starting from the upcoming coupon payments) ?

Comment: Price for swaps is usually quoted clean (without accrued).

Answer (score 1):

If you value an existing IRS then you value its official cashflows to their full extent, i.e. *implicitly including accrued interest*. When an IRS is 'torn up' (or 'bought out' or 'terminated') it is natural to expect discounted value of all of its cashflows.

When a new IRS is 'created' (or 'written' or 'executed') partway through a period it will contain one (or more) 'stub-period'. These are unnatural length periods which  settle to an interpolated rate representing the length of the coupon. Since new swaps are rarely created with a backwards start date this is *implicitly without accrued interest.*